# Writing a script to transform varchar data in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to write an SQL update script that converts varchar data.

Strings of the form `8:0:27:e:2b:4b` have to be converted to `08 00 27 0E 2B 4B`.

Comment: And then? What happens then?

Comment: "a script" - an SQL update statement or a stored procedure? And is the datatype varchar? Edit your question text and title.

Comment: Have you tried something? Post some sample code.

Comment: @astander when the data in the table is converted, i will use it in other DML operations, it is not usable in the current form.

Comment: @JanDoggen the datatype is varchar and i am doing it in Ubuntu so i will run a script which will be in the form of an update statement

Comment: I wrote 'edit your question'. Don't hide information away in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a table named `a` and a field named `fa` that contained that value, this query would do it for you:

```
SELECT
  UPPER(LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fa, ':', 1), 2, '0')),
  UPPER(LPAD(REPLACE(LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fa, ':', -5), 2), ':', ''), 2, '0')),
  UPPER(LPAD(REPLACE(LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fa, ':', -4), 2), ':', ''), 2, '0')),
  UPPER(LPAD(REPLACE(LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fa, ':', -3), 2), ':', ''), 2, '0')),
  UPPER(LPAD(REPLACE(LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fa, ':', -2), 2), ':', ''), 2, '0')),
  UPPER(LPAD(REPLACE(LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fa, ':', -1), 2), ':', ''), 2, '0'))
FROM a
```

and here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cde10/13/0) to prove it.

Now, that query puts each part in its own field - you could of course concatenate those values if you wanted to - that's up to you.

Comment: Doesn't convert the characters to uppercase.